# Cocoa Scroll view keeps bouncing on mavericks in the middle of the file

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview

Does anybody know why when scrolling (via two finger touch) rapidly up and down it "catches" quite often and bounces incorrectly in the middle of a scrollview?  This behavior is quite annoying and makes for a bad user experience.

Xcode has scrollviews which bounce both horizontally and vertically and doesn't nearly-as-often get stuck this way.

Comment: Do you have code to share?

Answer (score 2):

That seems like a bug in NSScrollView.

You can enable predominant axis scrolling, which mostly eliminates the problem:

```
scrollView.usesPredominantAxisScrolling = YES;
```

Or, you can disable horizontal bouncing, which is what Finder does:

```
scrollView.horizontalScrollElasticity = NSScrollElasticityNone;
```